# How to force Jooma! to send emails in HTML format?

Tags: php, html, email, joomla, phpmailer

I know Joomla! using phpMailer for sending email and also know that if I want to send emails in html format I must do such below:

```
$mailer->isHTML(true);
```

But this method needs to edit Joomla! default components and modules source code and I don't like to do this. For example if I want to send joomla! registration email in html format I must edit multiple files.
Now my question is how to force Joomla! to send all emails in html format without edit each component or module default source code.
Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest the usual way get this kind of change done: Fork it, alter it to add the feature and submit a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

On a customer project we used a 3rd party module (we used [AcyMailing](http://www.acyba.com/acymailing/432-improve-your-joomla-registration-confirmation-email.html)) which replaced some Joomla function and which allowed to send out registration emails as HTML emails. This was our solution as we didn´t wish to hack core components.

Another possible idea might be to use a template overwrite and during that you trigger your own function here as the default build in function. But that depends on your needs and might give you only some idea which you can follow and no real solution.